# How can I check to see if my checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a list of checkboxes that I would like to monitor.  They are loaded on the form something like this:

In the Java script the conditional compilation is turned off and I have a syntax error.  Can someone please show me how to go about this the right or maybe point me to a tutorial that may help?

Thanks.

So I put the JQuery function inside a working foreach loop to check the checked status of each checkbox but the alert says checked each even for those that are not checked.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
foreach (var course in courses.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
              if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                     alert('checked');
              }
              else
                 alert('unchecked');
         });
       });
   </script>
}
```

Comment: There are two code sections in your question. What do you want to achieve with each?

Comment: Question is confusing. Needs some ordered detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find you whether any checkbox is checked or not in javascript by getting its checked status as below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var checkStatus = document.getElementById("checkBoxId").checked;
    alert(checkStatus);
</script>
```

through jQuery you can do like this:

```
    if($('#checkBoxId').is(':checked') ){
     //your logic
    }
```

you can trap `change` event of checkbox like this:

```
 $('input:checkbox').change(function(){ 
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('checked');
    }
    else
        alert('unchecked');
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra121/EGWYT/)

Comment: So I tried something like this: function checkDropDowns() {
var trueFalse=document.getElementById("checkbox").checked
if (trueFalse == false) {

    //set the first item in each dropdown list on the form to text value of a dropdown list to Monday.

     @Html.DropDownList("dayString", Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals("Monday") })) 

}


alert(trueFalse).  Is there an easy way that I can change the first value of in a dropdown list?

Comment: I can't seem to get access to the other dropdown lists on the form using the keyword 'this'.  How can I access properties of drowdown lists that are on the form?

Comment: keyword this value depends on the scope you're using it. if you want to access other dropdownlists, access them by grabbing them from their Id or Class or their tagname. $('.className') or $('<select>') or $('#Id')

Comment: Can I use $('#id) in a JavaScript? Or would I have to change my function(checkDropdowns() to JQuery Document.Ready()?

Comment: you cannot use $('#id') in javascript.that's jquery. and if you have placed your jquery code in head, you will have to wrap it up in jQuery.ready

Comment: I put the JQuery block inside the loop that loads the checkboxes to test if selected but it's not working properly.  Can you help me with what's missing from my code?  I've added it to the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: first. don't add the entire script inside foreach loop. just place that script at the end of the body.without loops. second inside the click event of #saveBtn you are doing `$('#checkbox').is(':checked')`, so it will see only if checkbox with id #checkbox is checked or not, it won't look into others.

Comment: Thanks guys they both worked but I had to use the code outside of the loop. Not quit solving my overall issue but you answered my questions and allowed me to move forward.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the checkboxes in you page and store the values of checked ones in an array like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

var selected = new Array();
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function()
{
    selected.push($(this).val());
});

});

   </script>
```

Comment: Sorry about the concussion.  The first block of code works well I would just like to know how to format the JavaScript to check for checked boxes.  Thanks.

Comment: @CloudyKooper, instead of checking for checked boxes, slacker has given you a selector to grab an array of them. This is basically what you asked for. Now you can apply any operation to them.